# Executing jar file in java

Tags: java, jar

i'm executing a jar file in java. so far my code works perfectly.

im executing epubcheck via java because its a console application

here is the address of the epubcheck

https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck

except when the name of the file that i need to browse contains 
' sign
and space on the folder name or space on the file name.

here is the error on folder name

```
Unrecognized argument: 'Files\1.epub'
```

here is the error when the file name contains '

```
Unrecognized argument: 'the'
```

this is my code

```
String a = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\epubcheck-4.0.1\\" + "epubcheck.jar";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar" + " " + a + " " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

here is how to run the epubchecker

```
java -jar epubcheck.jar file.epub
```

but when i run it on command prompt manually it didn't give me an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should quote the tokens that make up your command line. Use the `.exec(String[])` version

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java"
     , "-jar"
     , a
     , selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding quotes to the command string DOES NOT WORK.

The javadoc for `exec(String, ...)` says this:

> More precisely, the command string is broken into tokens using a `StringTokenizer` created by the call `new StringTokenizer(command)` with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array `cmdarray`, in the same order.

If you then look at the javadoc for `StringTokenizer`, it says:

> The StringTokenizer methods do not distinguish among identifiers, numbers, and quoted strings, nor do they recognize and skip comments.

and

> The tokenizer [produced by `new StringTokeniser(string)`] uses the default delimiter set, which is " \t\n\r\f".

In other words, `exec` will split the command string into arguments, ignoring any quoting.

Any quotes (or double-backslash escapes) will simply be treated as notmal characters.  For example:

```
    exec("java -jar \"C:/Users/My User Name/foo.jar\"");
```

will attempt to look for a JAR file called `"C:/Users/My`.  Yes ... there is a leading quote at the start of the pathname.

You can avoid this problem by doing the argument yourself; e.g.

```
    exec(new String[]{"java",
                      "-jar",
                      "C:/Users/My User Name/foo.jar"});
```

Notice there are no added quotes.

---

It is also possible to use a shell to deal with quoting if (for some reason) your application is provided with an already-quoted pathname.  For example (Linux / Unix / Mac OSX)

```
    exec(new String[]{"bash", 
                      "-c",
                      "java -jar \"/home/me/silly dir/foo.jar\""});
```